# IRM and sharepoint 2016 intermittent activation issues (on Premise)

Tags: 2016, irm

we have a very strange issue, we are using(windows 2016 for both):

1) RMS 2016

2) Sharepoint 2016 (September 2018 CU)

We were able to configure "Information Rights Management" after several tries.

The system initially kept showing the "Active Directory Rights Management Service Client MSIPC.DLL is present but could not be configured properly".

We finally were able to  configure the intergration, but users were not able to use IRM.

In Central admin we keep getting the same error message: if we restart the farm(restart services and iisresest) and keep the administrative user logged (on the same RDP session that restarted the farm) then the integration seems to work ok. But, if we logoff from server and logon again the integration stop working.

With the permission and RmsAnalyzer-x64 seems everything is fine.
It seems like an issue is with the user profile, but we cannot figure out what it could be.

Please help me with this.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: at the ULS we have only that execption that means nothing to us and google:

An unhandled exception occured. Watson will be invoked. StackTrace: 
 at ipcauth.dll: (sig=2ecde6bd-d57c-4a6a-ac61-f406517cb93b|1|ipcauth.pdb, offset=1C797)
 at msipc.dll: (sig=3607d3d0-7b11-4cc7-82ad-633e4cd3efb8|1|msipc.pdb, offset=B154F)
 at msipc.dll: (offset=B131F)
 at msipc.dll: (offset=5AC72)
 at msipc.dll: (offset=499BE)
 ...
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.ni.dll: (sig=c4a30a98-4d88-637a-6052-e98470ced866|1|Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.ni.pdb, offset=104BC5)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the user policy on the server to 'do not forcefully unload user profile' for me it solves problems with FBA sites stopping to auth users, but your case of logging out farm admin looks very similar.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately seems to not work, every time i logoff the settings keep not working  again

Answer (score 0):

By contacting the support it seems like a glitch in the Central Administration: from a user point of view the IRM is working fine despite we get the error in Central Admin.